# Silverstripe not using HomePage.ss as Chrome?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Hi I followed the Silverstripe lesson https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/working-with-multiple-templates-1, and even tried to download the code from repository but when I tried to create templates/HomePage.ss as chrome Silverstripe still uses Page.ss.  Clearly lesson says "It first looks in the main templates/ directory to find the chrome for this page. If it finds HomePage.ss in there, it will select that as your chrome."  What is missing?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Silverstripe is buggy, I got same issue.  Just switch to Wordpress.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that you are conflating the idea between a `Page` template, and a `HomePage` template.
The `Page` 'chrome' template (as the lesson calls it) resides in `templates/` because `Page` class is *not* namespaced, or that is it resides in the *root* namespace.
The `HomePage` class on the other hand *is* namespaced, and this must be reflected in the path to the template.

[image: namespace of HomePage]

- A `main` template (the 'chrome'), the template should be in `templates/SilverStripe/Lessons/`
- A `Layout` template should reside in the same base, but with a Layout folder; `templates/SilverStripe/Lessons/Layout`

This information *is* featured in the lesson.

[image: Lesson text describing the answer to the question]

I understand you are frustrated, but spreading fear uncertainty and doubt about bugs before finding the answer to your question is not a nice thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a few folders in the templates folder, as described in that lesson:

> Make a directory called templates/SilverStripe/Lessons. In that directory, create another directory called Layout/. In that directory, create HomePage.ss. The full path should be templates/SilverStripe/Lessons/Layout/HomePage.ss.

So you basically need to move your file from templates/HomePage.ss to templates/SilverStripe/Lessons/Layout/HomePage.ss

Comment: This answer is wrong. HomePage.ss is a layout in this case not a chrome.